# Intermediate Jacobian under group action

Tags: hodge-theory, jacobians, fano-varieties

Let $X$ be a smooth Fano threefold with a finite group $G$ action.  Assume that the orbit space $X/G$ is smooth.  Is it true that $J(X/G)\cong J(X)^G$ As an abelian variety? Here, $J(X)^G$ is the $G$-invariant part of $J(X)$.

I am particular interested in the case that $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2=\langle 1,\tau\rangle$ and $\tau$ is an involution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because there is no reason for $J(X)^G$ to be connected. Here is a silly example: consider a smooth elliptic curve  $C\subset \mathbb{P}^3$ given by $\sum x_i^2=\sum a_ix_i^2=0$; take for $X$ $\mathbb{P}^3$ with $C$ blown up, and let $\tau $ be the involution of $\mathbb{P}^3$ which changes the sign of one coordinate. We have a $G$-equivariant isomorphism $J(X) \cong JC $, and $\tau $ acts on $JC$ ($\cong C$)
with 4 fixed points, while $J(X/G)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for such nice example,  If we know J(X)^G is connected, is this equality true? I am thinking about a particular example, say X is a smooth cubic threefold with a specific involution $\tau$ and I know the $\tau$-invariant part of J(X) is a Prym variety associated with a discriminant curve from the conic fibration.  I was wondering if there is a particular nice situation such that this equality holds. I mean if J(X)^G has nice property, say irreducibility, smoothness, then does this equality hold?

Comment: You must certainly ask for $J(X)^G$ to be connected, but I doubt that it is sufficient. If it holds you get an isogeny  $J(X/G)\rightarrow J(X)^G$, but I don't see why it should be an isomorphism.